# How to update Vuetify to project created using Vue-cli-2

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to update Vuetify in a vue application created using Vue Cli 2. The current version is `0.17`. This is very old version and causing a lot of problems. I need to upgrade this to latest version `1.1.8`.

**What I've tried:**

1. remove existing vuetify plugin, updated `package.json` to the
   current version and run `npm i -S vuetify`.
2. run `vue add vuetify`
3. The documentation regd this shows invalid [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start). which has been [notified](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetifyjs.com/issues/549) to vuetify team

**Problem**

All these methods works but the out put is not as desired. The browser **reloads endlessly** when I run `npm run dev`. I'm not able to debug or even check the screen changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update `vuetify` you've to remove and install new version of the `vuetify` using the following commands.
`npm remove --save vuetify`
`npm install --save vuetify@latest`

**Cause of the relaoding problem when updating vuetify**

Vuetify **select** is emitting on-change event during page load, if data is being fetched in the **select**. Prior to 1.0.0 it was not like that.

If someone faces the same issue make sure all the codes in the on-change event run after the page/component is mounted.